# How can I make a background image larger?

Tags: html, css

I've added a background image to my html code, it's a yellow arrow. I am using it as a background image because I want to have text inside it. The only problem is that I don't know how to make it larger.

Here is how it should look like

[image]

How mine looks like

[image]

link to the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGDX9.jpg

```css
.post-header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #20cfcf;
    background-image: url("../img2/header_background.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 60Vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.post-header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #172025
}

.post-header h1 {
    font-size: 92pt;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: em;
}



.founders {
    margin-top: -6em;
    
}



.arrow {
    background: url("../img2/arrow.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="post-header">
         <div class="wrapper">
             
            <h2>HI. WE'RE TILDE.</h2>
            <h1>WE LIVE AND <br> BREATHE CODE.</h1>
            <img src="img2/founders.png" class="founders" height="294px" width=425px alt="">
            
            <div class="arrow-box">
                <a href="#" class="arrow">Meet the team</a>
            </div>
            
</section>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put a copy of your image in a public place and link to it so your sample actually shows the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we go, enjoy =)

```css
.post-header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #20cfcf;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdoebt2SsCGoDGZRvW4FUiBRKswQ8EVJHExA&usqp=CAU");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 60Vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.post-header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #172025
}

.post-header h1 {
    font-size: 92pt;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: em;
}



.founders {
    margin-top: -6em;
    
}



.arrow-box {
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/gp3z7z5.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:2.5rem;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="post-header">
         <div class="wrapper">
             
            <h2>HI. WE'RE TILDE.</h2>
            <h1>WE LIVE AND <br> BREATHE CODE.</h1>
            <img src="https://img.pngio.com/hidden-founders-cto-as-a-service-founder-png-900_957.png" class="founders" height="294px" width=425px alt="">
            
            <div class="arrow-box">
                <a href="#" class="arrow">Meet the team</a>
            </div>
            
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stretch the image size to the container try to use

> `background-size: cover;`

Comment: It did stretch out, how can I make it bigger now? I've tried to give both the a element and the div a width + height but that did nothing.